# How to make the PERF_COUNT_SW_CONTEXT_SWITCHES config in perf_event_open() work?

Tags: c++, profiling, perf, context-switch

I'm setting up profiling for a software I've written but I am not able to get the context-switch count working using `perf_event_open`.

To test the problem, I tried using the sample code provided on the `perf_event_open` `man_page` as well. Using `sched_yield` and running a parallel process on the same core using taskset to force context-switches. The count for context-switches using `perf_event_open()` still remains 0. (While using perf stat I get non-zero numbers : in the thousands for large loops). I've tried doing a file read / using mmap to force page faults as well.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <linux/perf_event.h>
#include <asm/unistd.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
using namespace std;
int buf_size_shift = 8;

static unsigned perf_mmap_size(int buf_size_shift)
{
    return ((1U << buf_size_shift) + 1) * sysconf(_SC_PAGESIZE);
}

static long
perf_event_open(struct perf_event_attr *hw_event, pid_t pid,
            int cpu, int group_fd, unsigned long flags)
{
        int ret;

        ret = syscall(__NR_perf_event_open, hw_event, pid, cpu,
                      group_fd, flags);
        return ret;
}


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

       struct perf_event_attr pe;
       long long count;
       int fd;

       memset(&pe, 0, sizeof(struct perf_event_attr));
       pe.type = PERF_TYPE_SOFTWARE;
       //pe.sample_type = PERF_SAMPLE_CALLCHAIN; /* this is what allows you to obtain callchains */

       pe.size = sizeof(struct perf_event_attr);
       pe.config = PERF_COUNT_SW_CONTEXT_SWITCHES;
       pe.disabled = 1;
       pe.exclude_kernel = 1;
       pe.sample_period = 1000;
       pe.exclude_hv = 1;

       fd = perf_event_open(&pe, 0, -1, -1, 0); 
       if (fd == -1) {
          fprintf(stderr, "Error opening leader %llx\n", pe.config);
          exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
       }

       /* associate a buffer with the file */
       struct perf_event_mmap_page *mpage;
       mpage = (perf_event_mmap_page*) mmap(NULL,  perf_mmap_size(buf_size_shift),
        PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED,
       fd, 0);
       if (mpage == (struct perf_event_mmap_page *)-1L) {
        close(fd);
        return -1;
       }

       ioctl(fd, PERF_EVENT_IOC_RESET, 0);
       ioctl(fd, PERF_EVENT_IOC_ENABLE, 0);

       printf("Measuring instruction count for this printf\n");
       long long sum = 0;
       for (long long i = 0; i < 10000000000; i++) {
           sum += i;
           if (i%1000000 == 0)
               cout << i << " : " << sum << endl;
       } 

       ioctl(fd, PERF_EVENT_IOC_DISABLE, 0);
       read(fd, &count, sizeof(long long));

       printf("Used %lld cs\n", count);

       close(fd);
}
```

This code for `type = PERF_COUNT_SOFTWARE` and `config = PERF_COUNT_SW_CONTEXT_SWITCHES` outputs 0 in the count even with forced context-switches. While other metrics are working.

On using the mmap ring buffer, I see `PERF_RECORD_SWITCH` records on reading it, while according to my understanding is that context-switch events are being recorded.

Any information on how the perf count and the data in the ring buffer is related is also appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The events are not counted because you disable events from the kernel (`exclude_kernel = 1;`), and `PERF_TYPE_SOFTWARE` events are generally *provided by the kernel*.

If you remove the `exclude_kernel`, the events are counted.

The connection between the count and the recorded events in the ring buffer is the `sample_period`. Your setting of `pe.sample_period = 1000;` means that every 1000 switch events, a `PERF_RECORD_SAMPLE` event is written to the ring buffer.

The following example to read the buffer is only to illustrate the general approach. In practice you need to handle events that wrap around the end of the buffer and do more consistency checks.

```
   auto tail = mpage->data_tail;
   const auto head = mpage->data_head;
   const auto size = mpage->data_size;
   char* data = reinterpret_cast<char*>(mpage) + sysconf(_SC_PAGESIZE);
   int events = 0;
   while (true) {
       if (tail >= head) break;
       auto event_header_p = (struct perf_event_header*)(data + (tail % size));
       std::cout << "event << " << event_header_p->type << ", size: " << event_header_p->size << "\n";
       tail += event_header_p->size;
       events++;
   }
```

You should find a corresponding number of events of type `PERF_RECORD_SAMPLE == 9` in the buffer (unless there is an overflow). If you want to read them, you need to cast the pointer to an appropriate struct. The actual layout of `PERF_RECORD_SAMPLE` events - or any other events - depends on your `perf_event_attr` configuration and is documented in [`perf_event_open`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/perf_event_open.2.html).

Comment: Did he also need to set `context_switch` flag?

Comment: @intrigued_66 no, those are specific recorded, not counters to be read.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand. What is the difference between recorded and reading counters?

Comment: I'm afraid `perf recrod` is too complex to fully explain in a comment. In general, you can either have the kernel write individual events into a buffer and read those events from the buffer occasionally - or you can occasionally read a single value (event counter).